# decode to accept special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, decode

I have the following js function:

```
$(function() {
  $(".search").keyup(function() {
    var searchid = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'search=' + searchid;
    if (searchid != '') {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          $("#result").html(html).show();
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });

  jQuery("#result").live("click", function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = encodeURIComponent($("<div/>").html($name).text());
    window.open('searchPage.php?user_query=' + decoded, '_self', false);

    $('#searchid').val(decoded);
  });
  jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.hasClass("search")) {
      var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();

    }
  });
  $('#searchid').click(function() {
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

At its current state it does not accept special characters. In the sense that its a search suggestion where when a user click on a item suggested it takes them to that search result. This work fines with regular characters but as soon as a special character such as apostrophe, a slash or any special character is thrown in it doesn't work anymore.

this is the area where the decoding is done:

```
var $clicked = $(e.target);
var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
var decoded = encodeURIComponent($("<div/>").html($name).text());
```

Comment: `var dataString = 'search=' + encodeURIComponent(searchid);`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but unfortunatetly the issue persist